# Expanding APT-GET Repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

Wow, I'm here posting about Linux. Never thought I'd see the day, but I've been shown the light by a smart guy and a few VMs and man pages later and her I am.

I think I've managed to get my Ubuntu VM to punch through the company proxy to get out to the net (I've used CURL to download Valgrind) and now I want to stretch my legs with APT-GET a bit. I thought something fun to do would be install Nethack, surely its in an APT repository. I've looked into the SOURCES file to see the repositories I can reference.. what is the universe/multiverse business? Who is Wily Werewolf and am I looking at his repositories? Where can I find more repositories to stick in there, specifically one hosting a Nethack (tiles version please, I can't do the ASCII) so then I can use APT-GET and pull it down?

Comment: The dungeon game?

Comment: Absolutely the dungeon game :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after the X11 version of `nethack` simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install nethack-x11
```

And then the glory of this old game will be revealed, as installed on my system:

[image]

No fiddling with repositories here, it is [in the Universe Repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/nethack-x11) which should be activated my default on your system...

Comment: wow .. i went to their page and didn't see anything about this only to download source .. nice catch :D

Comment: You can see it by running `apt-cache search nethack` on your Ubuntu system :)

Comment: lol yeah .. i foolishly just looked on the web .. never bothered to actually search Ubuntu :( ... lol .. my bad

Comment: ok, so here is my problem then. I've managed to get out through my proxy by setting environment variables via the environment file in etc, CURL works fine and my credentials are passed through. I suspect APT-GET isn't getting through though, I thought it was because SUDO uses a minimal set of env variables for security. So I went and edited the sudoers file and confirmed my proxy variables are being preserved (I've got ones for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP). I still get this, however ![Error](http://i.imgur.com/41gmD70.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was taken from the Ubuntu documentation for an explination about sources:

```
 Main - Officially supported software.

 Restricted - Supported software that is not available under a completely free license.

 Universe - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software.

 Multiverse - Software that is not free.
```

As for Wily I believe is the version of Ubuntu you are running .. they all have code names like 16.04 is xenial